# Access dictionary to X depth with a list of X values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

### Situation

I want to make a function that makes me free to give a full dictionary path parameter, and get back the value or node I need, without doing it node by node.

### Code

This is the function. Obviously, as is now, it throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. But it's only for getting the idea.

```
def get_section(api_data, section):
    if "/" in section:
        section = section.split("/")
        return api_data.json()[section]            
    return api_data.json()[section]
```

### Example

#### JSON

```
{
  "component": {
    "name": "gino",
    "measures": [
      {
        "value": "12",
      },
      {
        "value": "14"
      }
    ]
  },
  "metrics": {
    ...
  }
}
```

#### Expectation

```
analyses = get_section(analyses_data, "component/measures") # Returns measures node

analyses = get_section(analyses_data, "component/name") # Returns 'gino'

analyses = get_section(analyses_data, "component/measures/value") # Returns error, because it's ambigous
```

### Request

How can I do it?

---

###### Edits

- Added examples for clarity

Comment: So you want to go to some deep index of your json when you have the absolute path? I.e. table/name/age -> json[table][name][age]? Could you add some dummy data and your expected behaviour? Otherwise what is wrong with simply directly accessing said depth from path?

Comment: @JasonChia Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cool solution could be:

```
def get_section(api_data, section):
    return [api_data := api_data[sec] for sec in section.split("/")][-1]
```

So if you execute it with:

```
analyses_data = {
    "analyses": {
        "dates": {
            "xyz": "abc"
        }
    }
}
print(get_section(analyses_data, "analyses/dates/xyz")) # Returns: abc
```

Or since you are accessing a json using a custom method:

```
print(get_section(analyses_data.json(), "analyses/dates/xyz")) # Returns: abc
```

This works because the `:=` operator in python is a variable assignment that returns the assigned value, so it loops all the parts of the `section` string by reassigning the `api_data` variable to the result of accessing that key and storing the result of every assignment in a list. Then with the `[-1]` at the end it returns the last assignment that corresponds to the last accessed key (a.k.a the last accessed dictionary level).

Comment: This works, but I can't understand how. Could you provide a little explanation?

Comment: Updated the answer with a little explenation